# Combine Query of Android database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have Join query that find data from three table so how can I know the data is founded from which table

```
select text from table1 where title ='Vishal'  union all select text from table2 where title ='Vishal'  union all select text from table3 where title ='Vishal'
```

This query give me my desired output but I want to know
title match from which table and I want to get the Table name

Comment: You need to be much clearer with your question.  Your answer could be union, or join, or subquery, or something else.  There's not enough info.  Describe in detail the schema of the 3 tables and what you want to do.

Comment: you can return some hint with the data to identify

Comment: explain brief your question with some of example

Comment: Now it is comfortable ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a column with a constant values to the results:

```
select text, 'table1' as source from table1 where title ='Vishal'
union all
select text, 'table2'           from table2 where title ='Vishal'
union all
select text, 'table3'           from table3 where title ='Vishal'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a smart solution, but how about?

```
select text as text1, null as text2, null as text3 from table1 where title ='Vishal'
union all
select null as text1, text as text2, null as text3 from table2 where title ='Vishal'
union all
select null as text1, null as text2, text as text3 from table3 where title ='Vishal'


// Run your sql query

for (results){
    if (results[i].text1 != null){
        // match table1
    }
    else if (results[i].text2 != null){
        // match table2
    }
    else if (results[i].text3 != null){
        // match table3
    }
}
```